# Trigger a command upon every `crontab -e` edit

Tags: linux, unix, backup, crontab, cronjob

We are using a shared Linux server account where as everyone comes and edits the crontab. Usually we take a backup like this

```
crontab -l > `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d\_\%H:\%M:\%S.txt`
```

Is there an elegant way to trigger this command automatically upon every successful edit by `crontab -e` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *inotifywait*, which resides in a package  called *inotify-tools*.

The command might be something like

```
   while inotifywait -e close_write /path/to/file/ToWatch ; do /path/to/executable/script; done
```

Just remember to make the script to be executed, containing the command you wrote, executable.